# Perl : Scrape website and how to download PDF files from the website using Perl Selenium:Chrome

Tags: selenium, perl, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm studying Scraping website using Selenium:Chrome on Perl, I just wondering how can I download all pdf files from year 2017 to 2021 and store it into a folder from this website https://www.fda.gov/drugs/warning-letters-and-notice-violation-letters-pharmaceutical-companies/untitled-letters-2021 . So far this is what I've done

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Selenium::Chrome;
use File::Slurp;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
use File::Path;
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);
use LWP::Simple;


my $collection_name = "mre_zen_test3";
make_path("$collection_name");

#DECLARE SELENIUM DRIVER
my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new;

#NAVIGATE TO SITE
print "trying to get toc_url\n";
$driver->navigate('https://www.fda.gov/drugs/warning-letters-and-notice-violation-letters-pharmaceutical-companies/untitled-letters-2021');
sleep(8);

#GET PAGE SOURCE
my $toc_content = $driver->get_page_source();
$toc_content =~ s/[^\x00-\x7f]//g;
write_file("toc.html", $toc_content);
print "writing toc.html\n";
sleep(5);
$toc_content = read_file("toc.html");
```

This script only download the entire content of the website. Hope someone here can help me and teach me. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's just taking the main page, not the things you want.  Need to get to that pdf link and `click` it, then navigate to year 2020 and do the same, etc.  I can't write that right now but see [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) for what you can use (and search this site)

Comment: yeah , I'm looking for samples but I can't seem to understand those examples. but I will research for more examplese

Comment: Alright, do that. I may be able to post something as well...

Comment: Updated my post some, have a look.  I intend to edit more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some working code, to help you get going hopefully

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Path::Tiny;  # only convenience

use Selenium::Chrome;

my $base_url = q(https://www.fda.gov/drugs/)
    . q(warning-letters-and-notice-violation-letters-pharmaceutical-companies/);

my $show = 1;  # to see navigation. set to false for headless operation
    
# A little demo of how to set some browser options
my %chrome_capab = do {
    my @cfg = ($show) 
        ? ('window-position=960,10', 'window-size=950,1180')
        : 'headless';
    'extra_capabilities' => { 'goog:chromeOptions' => { args => [ @cfg ] } }
};

my $drv = Selenium::Chrome->new( %chrome_capab );

my @years = 2017..2021;
foreach my $year (@years) {
    my $url = $base_url . "untitled-letters-$year";

    $drv->get($url);

    say "\nPage title: ", $drv->get_title;
    sleep 1 if $show;

    my $elem = $drv->find_element(
        q{//li[contains(text(), 'PDF')]/a[contains(text(), 'Untitled Letter')]}
    );
    sleep 1 if $show;
    
    # Downloading the file is surprisingly not simple with Selenium itself 
    # (see text). But as we found the link we can get its url and then use 
    # Selenium-provided user-agent (it's LWP::UserAgent)
    my $href = $elem->get_attribute('href');
    say "pdf's url: $href";

    my $response = $drv->ua->get($href);
    die $response->status_line if not $response->is_success;

    say "Downloading 'Content-Type': ", $response->header('Content-Type'); 
    my $filename = "download_$year.pdf";
    say "Save as $filename";
    path($filename)->spew( $response->decoded_content );
}
```

This takes shortcuts, switches approaches, and sidesteps some issues (which one need resolve for a fuller utility of this useful tool). It downloads one pdf from each page; to download all we need to change the XPath expression used to locate them

```
my @hrefs = 
    map { $_->get_attribute('href') } 
    $drv->find_elements(
        # There's no ends-with(...) in XPath 1.0 (nor matches() with regex)
        q{//li[contains(text(), '(PDF)')]}
      . q{/a[starts-with(@href, '/media/') and contains(@href, '/download')]} 
    );
```

Now loop over the links, forming filenames more carefully, and download each like in the program above. I can fill the gaps further if there's need for that.

The code puts the pdf files on disk, in its working directory. Please review that before running this so to make sure that nothing gets overwritten!

See [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) for starters.

---

Note: there is no need for Selenium for this particular task; it's all straight-up HTTP requests, no JavaScript. So `LWP::UserAgent` or `Mojo` would do it just fine. But I take it that you want to learn how to use Selenium, since it often is needed and is useful.

Comment: I tried the script that you made but it seems the downloaded pdf files were corrupted or something, I can't open it .

Comment: @gakusei Oh? :(  Works for me, exactly as posted.  I'll test more, once I get to edit further ... what Perl are you on? (Or, what version of `Selenium::Remote::Driver`.)